# How to assign words to numbers in Microsoft Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

I am creating a database with a GUI in Access. In the database I have a column called "Status" that has a bunch of numbers like "01, 02, 03, 04, 02, 02, 06...." Each number means something like 01 means empty, 02 means waiting for call and so on. I created a GUI, and in the "Status" text box I want the MEANING of those numbers to be displayed because right now only the numbers from the "status column" show. How do I do it? Do the numbers in the status column have to be type string or type integer?

Comment: Integer and please show your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access jargon you need to...

- Add another table with two fields called (say) StatusCode and StatusMeaning. Make StatusCode the primary key; on the assumption it's not necessarily a 'number', I'd keep its type as Text.
- Load the new table with the meaning of each possible code
- Go into the Relationships window and add a one-to-many relation between the two tables.
- Create a new select query; at the prompt, select both tables, then add to the query all the fields of the original table + the StatusMeaning field from the new one
- Set the form's RecordSource property to the query rather than the original table

You will now be able to change the ControlSource of the text box to StatusMeaning and get the output you want.

(PS - I started writing this before I saw dotNET's answer pop up, but then amended it accordingly before posting in the aim of making it complementary: varchar = the Text field type, foreign keys = what the Relationship window sets up, and using SQL JOINS and creating a view is what using the query builder does for you.)

Comment: Very well described solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Common solution to this problem is to create a table with two columns named ID and Name, then put your codes in the first column and their "meanings" in the second. Now you can join your main table with this second table using SQL JOINS and create a view which shows just the meanings and not those 01, 02 values.

The new table would look something like this:

```
ID (int)        Name (varchar)
--------        --------------
       1        Emtpy
       2        Waiting
       3        Ready
```

and so on. That is you'll add all possible statuses in this table and assign them unique IDs. Then use these IDs in the main table as foreign keys. These two table can then be joined through SQL. I recall that Access even allows you to do this linking through column properties. Haven't used it for so many years, but someone else might be able to guide you about that feature.